# Magento 2 create order programmatically with product custom options having multiple values

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to create a magento 2 order programmatically with product custom options. I have created an associative array to pass the product id with qty and option array as label with value, But it give me Error related with specified request.

Help please

Comment: please post code with error